# I am creating a web application using Laravel, vue-router and MySQL database

Tags: laravel, vue-component

I am creating a web application using Laravel, vue-router and MySQL database. I created a dashboard component and a bank component. When I run my project, the Dashboard component loads with all the CSS and javascript. But when I change to the Bank component, CSS may be loaded but some javascript cannot run. After refreshing the entire bank component page, the previously non-running javascript then executes.

this is my web.php file

```
    <?php


Route::get('/{any}', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->where('any', '.*');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

This is my index.js file

import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'


Vue.use(VueRouter)

import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard";
import Bank from "./components/Bank";
import Demo from "./components/Demo";
import Company from "./components/Company";


const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'dashboard',
            component: Dashboard,

        },
        {
            path: '/bank',
            name: 'bank',
            component: Bank,
        },
        {
            path: '/company',
            name: 'company',
            component: Company
        },
    ],
})

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
});

This is my Dashboard Component file

<template>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Page-Title -->
        <div class="page-title-box">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h4 class="page-title">Dashboard</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <ol class="breadcrumb float-right">
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Stexo</a></li>
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Dashboard</li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end row -->
        </div>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xl-3">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-heading p-4">
                        <div class="mini-stat-icon float-right">
                            <i class="mdi mdi-cube-outline bg-primary  text-white"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <h5 class="font-16">Active Sessions</h5>
                        </div>
                        <h3 class="mt-4">43,225</h3>
                        <div class="progress mt-4" style="height: 4px;">
                            <div class="progress-bar bg-primary" role="progressbar" style="width: 75%" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                        </div>
                        <p class="text-muted mt-2 mb-0">Previous period<span class="float-right">75%</span></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xl-3">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-heading p-4">
                        <div class="mini-stat-icon float-right">
                            <i class="mdi mdi-briefcase-check bg-success text-white"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <h5 class="font-16">Total Revenue</h5>
                        </div>
                        <h3 class="mt-4">$73,265</h3>
                        <div class="progress mt-4" style="height: 4px;">
                            <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 88%" aria-valuenow="88" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                        </div>
                        <p class="text-muted mt-2 mb-0">Previous period<span class="float-right">88%</span></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xl-3">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-heading p-4">
                        <div class="mini-stat-icon float-right">
                            <i class="mdi mdi-tag-text-outline bg-warning text-white"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <h5 class="font-16">Average Price</h5>
                        </div>
                        <h3 class="mt-4">447</h3>
                        <div class="progress mt-4" style="height: 4px;">
                            <div class="progress-bar bg-warning" role="progressbar" style="width: 68%" aria-valuenow="68" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                        </div>
                        <p class="text-muted mt-2 mb-0">Previous period<span class="float-right">68%</span></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xl-3">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-heading p-4">
                        <div class="mini-stat-icon float-right">
                            <i class="mdi mdi-buffer bg-danger text-white"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <h5 class="font-16">Add to Card</h5>
                        </div>
                        <h3 class="mt-4">86%</h3>
                        <div class="progress mt-4" style="height: 4px;">
                            <div class="progress-bar bg-danger" role="progressbar" style="width: 82%" aria-valuenow="82" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                        </div>
                        <p class="text-muted mt-2 mb-0">Previous period<span class="float-right">82%</span></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-8">
                <div class="card m-b-30">
                    <div class="card-body">

                        <h4 class="mt-0 header-title mb-4">Area Chart</h4>

                        <div id="morris-area-example" class="morris-charts morris-chart-height"></div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end col -->

            <div class="col-xl-4">
                <div class="card m-b-30">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="mt-0 header-title mb-4">Donut Chart</h4>

                        <div id="morris-donut-example" class="morris-charts morris-chart-height"></div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end col -->
        </div>
        <!-- end row -->

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-4">
                <div class="card m-b-30">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="mt-0 header-title mb-4">Friends Suggestions</h4>
                        <div class="friends-suggestions">
                            <a href="#" class="friends-suggestions-list">
                                <div class="border-bottom position-relative">
                                    <div class="float-left mb-0 mr-3">
                                        <img src="front/images/users/user-2.jpg" alt="" class="rounded-circle thumb-md">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="suggestion-icon float-right mt-2 pt-1">
                                        <i class="mdi mdi-plus"></i>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="desc">
                                        <h5 class="font-14 mb-1 pt-2 text-dark">Ralph Ramirez</h5>
                                        <p class="text-muted">3 Friend suggest</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>

                            <a href="#" class="friends-suggestions-list">
                                <div class="border-bottom position-relative">
                                    <div class="float-left mb-0 mr-3">
                                        <img src="front/images/users/user-3.jpg" alt="" class="rounded-circle thumb-md">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="suggestion-icon float-right mt-2 pt-1">
                                        <i class="mdi mdi-plus"></i>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="desc">
                                        <h5 class="font-14 mb-1 pt-2 text-dark">Patrick Beeler</h5>
                                        <p class="text-muted">17 Friend suggest</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>

                            <a href="#" class="friends-suggestions-list">
                                <div class="border-bottom position-relative">
                                    <div class="float-left mb-0 mr-3">
                                        <img src="front/images/users/user-4.jpg" alt="" class="rounded-circle thumb-md">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="suggestion-icon float-right mt-2 pt-1">
                                        <i class="mdi mdi-plus"></i>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="desc">
                                        <h5 class="font-14 mb-1 pt-2 text-dark">Victor Zamora</h5>
                                        <p class="text-muted">12 Friend suggest</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>

                            <a href="#" class="friends-suggestions-list">
                                <div class="border-bottom position-relative">
                                    <div class="float-left mb-0 mr-3">
                                        <img src="front/images/users/user-5.jpg" alt="" class="rounded-circle thumb-md">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="suggestion-icon float-right mt-2 pt-1">
                                        <i class="mdi mdi-plus"></i>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="desc">
                                        <h5 class="font-14 mb-1 pt-2 text-dark">Bryan Lacy</h5>
                                        <p class="text-muted">18 Friend suggest</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>

                            <a href="#" class="friends-suggestions-list">
                                <div class="position-relative">
                                    <div class="float-left mb-0 mr-3">
                                        <img src="front/images/users/user-6.jpg" alt="" class="rounded-circle thumb-md">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="suggestion-icon float-right mt-2 pt-1">
                                        <i class="mdi mdi-plus"></i>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="desc">
                                        <h5 class="font-14 mb-1 pt-2 text-dark">James Sorrells</h5>
                                        <p class="text-muted mb-1">6 Friend suggest</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xl-4">
                <div class="card m-b-30">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="mt-0 header-title mb-4">Sales Analytics</h4>
                        <div id="morris-line-example" class="morris-chart" style="height: 360px"></div>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-xl-4">
                <div class="card m-b-30">
                    <div class="card-body">

                        <h4 class="mt-0 header-title mb-4">Recent Activity</h4>
                        <ol class="activity-feed mb-0">
                            <li class="feed-item">
                                <div class="feed-item-list">
                                    <p class="text-muted mb-1">Now</p>
                                    <p class="font-15 mt-0 mb-0">Andrei Coman posted a new article: <b class="text-primary">Forget UX Rowland</b></p>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="feed-item">
                                <p class="text-muted mb-1">Yesterday</p>
                                <p class="font-15 mt-0 mb-0">Andrei Coman posted a new article: <b class="text-primary">Designer Alex</b></p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="feed-item">
                                <p class="text-muted mb-1">2:30PM</p>
                                <p class="font-15 mt-0 mb-0">Zack Wetass, <b class="text-primary"> Developer Moreno</b></p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="feed-item pb-1">
                                <p class="text-muted mb-1">12:48 PM</p>
                                <p class="font-15 mt-0 mb-2">Zack Wetass, <b class="text-primary">UX Murphy</b></p>
                            </li>

                        </ol>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- START ROW -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-12">
                <div class="card m-b-30">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="mt-0 header-title mb-4">Active Deals</h4>
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-hover">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Status</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Amount</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Contact</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Location</th>
                                    <th scope="col" colspan="2">Date</th>

                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Philip Smead</td>
                                    <td><span class="badge badge-success">Delivered</span></td>
                                    <td>$9,420,000</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div>
                                            <img src="front/images/users/user-2.jpg" alt="" class="thumb-md rounded-circle mr-2"> Philip Smead
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>Houston, TX 77074</td>
                                    <td>15/1/2018</td>

                                    <td>
                                        <div>
                                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Brent Shipley</td>
                                    <td><span class="badge badge-warning">Pending</span></td>
                                    <td>$3,120,000</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div>
                                            <img src="front/images/users/user-3.jpg" alt="" class="thumb-md rounded-circle mr-2"> Brent Shipley
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>Oakland, CA 94612</td>
                                    <td>16/1/2019</td>

                                    <td>
                                        <div>
                                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Robert Sitton</td>
                                    <td><span class="badge badge-success">Delivered</span></td>
                                    <td>$6,360,000</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div>
                                            <img src="front/images/users/user-4.jpg" alt="" class="thumb-md rounded-circle mr-2"> Robert Sitton
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>Hebron, ME 04238</td>
                                    <td>17/1/2019</td>

                                    <td>
                                        <div>
                                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Alberto Jackson</td>
                                    <td><span class="badge badge-danger">Cancel</span></td>
                                    <td>$5,200,000</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div>
                                            <img src="front/images/users/user-5.jpg" alt="" class="thumb-md rounded-circle mr-2"> Alberto Jackson
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>Salinas, CA 93901</td>
                                    <td>18/1/2019</td>

                                    <td>
                                        <div>
                                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>David Sanchez</td>
                                    <td><span class="badge badge-success">Delivered</span></td>
                                    <td>$7,250,000</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div>
                                            <img src="front/images/users/user-6.jpg" alt="" class="thumb-md rounded-circle mr-2"> David Sanchez
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>Cincinnati, OH 45202</td>
                                    <td>19/1/2019</td>

                                    <td>
                                        <div>
                                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- END ROW -->

    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {}
</script>
This is my Bank component file
<template>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Page-Title -->
            <div class="page-title-box">
                <div class="row align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <h4 class="page-title">Add Bank</h4>
                    </div>
<!--                    <div class="col-sm-6">-->
<!--                        <ol class="breadcrumb float-right">-->
<!--                            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><router-link :to="{ name: 'dashboard' }">Dashboard</router-link></li>-->
<!--                            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><router-link :to="{ name: 'bank' }">Master</router-link></li>-->
<!--                            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><router-link :to="{ name: 'bank' }">Bank</router-link></li>-->
<!--                            <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Add Bank</li>-->
<!--                        </ol>-->
<!--                    </div>-->
                </div>
                <!-- end row -->
            </div>

<!--            Starting of Button Section-->

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="card m-b-30">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="button-items">
                                <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#elegantModalForm" class="btn btn-outline-primary waves-effect waves-light">Add Bank</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <!-- Starting of Modal -->
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="elegantModalForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
                 aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-notify modal-warning modal-lg" role="document">
                    <!--Content-->
                    <div class="modal-content form-elegant">
                        <!--Header-->
                        <div class="modal-header text-center">
                            <h3 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold py-2 white-text" id="myModalLabel"><strong>Add Bank Information</strong></h3>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <!--Body-->
                        <div class="modal-body">

                           <div class="container-fluid">
                               <form class="form-group">
                                   <div class="row">
                                       <div class="col-md-12 md-form">
                                           <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                           <label>Name of Bank *</label>
                                       </div>


                                   </div>
                                   <div class="row">
                                       <div class="col-md-12 md-form">
                                           <textarea type="text" class="form-control md-textarea"></textarea>
                                           <label>Address / Branch *</label>
                                       </div>
                                   </div>
                                   <div class="row">
                                       <div class="col-md-6 md-form">
                                           <select class="browser-default custom-select">
                                               <option value="">Account Holder Name</option>
                                               <option value="1">USA</option>
                                               <option value="2">Germany</option>
                                               <option value="3">France</option>
                                               <option value="4">Poland</option>
                                               <option value="5">Japan</option>
                                           </select>
                                       </div>

                                       <div class="col-md-6 md-form">
                                           <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                           <label>Bank Account *</label>
                                       </div>
                                   </div>

                                   <div class="row">
                                       <div class="col-md-6 md-form">
                                           <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                           <label>Bank Routing *</label>
                                       </div>

                                       <div class="col-md-6 md-form">
                                           <input type="date" class="form-control datepicker">
                                           <label>Opening Bal Date * </label>
                                       </div>
                                   </div>

                                   <div class="row">
                                       <div class="col-md-6 md-form">
                                           <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                           <label>Opening Balance *</label>
                                       </div>

                                       <div class="col-md-6 md-form">
                                           <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker">
                                           <label>Current Cheque no * </label>
                                       </div>
                                   </div>
                               </form>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--Footer-->
                        <div class="modal-footer mx-5 pt-3 mb-1">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button class="btn blue-gradient">Add</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--/.Content-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal -->
            <!-- Ending of Modal -->
<!--Ending of Button Section-->

        </div>
        <!-- end container-fluid -->
</template>

<script>
    export default {}
</script>
```

Comment: Provide your code to your question, please.

Comment: <?php

Route::get('/{any}', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->where('any', '.*');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Comment: above code is web.php file.

Comment: Provide code into question, no comment. Edit your question and paste a code.